# iOS- Navigating ViewControllers too quickly causes a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, crash, viewcontroller

I've built a solid soundboard app that uses view controllers to navigate through the list of sounds, but if I navigate too quickly the app will crash.

I'm using Objective-C and there is nothing special about the code, just `SystemSoundID` stuff and `AudioToolbox` framework. It's pretty much a default project.

Is this a memory issue? I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: can u show the crash logs

Comment: It's hard to know exactly without any code shown. If it's memory related, start up instruments, click on leaks and hit the record button while your app is running in the simulator.

Comment: sometimes only description doesn't work,you have to add code that shows how you did it.

Comment: See the problem is is it doesn't crash in the simulator, only on the device. I couldn't get a crash log. I know you guys want me to show code but really all I did was connect the controllers together using modal without animations. My only guess that it's memory related is when in the simulator switching through view controllers quickly will cause the memory to spike, so maybe there is code I can write to unload a view controller?

Comment: 32-bit (x86) vs 64-bit ARMV8 compiler differences?   The latter is rather more aggressive with releasing objects that the former, thus exposing over-release issues. I'd suggest using Instruments and the leaks and/or Zombies too.   It's likely that something is getting over-released.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips. I'll do some research on zombies as I don't know what that is.